# metacharacter "." in R on swirl session

Tags: r, regex, grepl

This is a question from a swirl course:

The goal is to filter and print out the location data both begins and ends with a vowel.

Here is the code:

```
    start_end_vowel<- "^[AEIOU]{1}.+[aeiou]{1}$"   #Q1
    vowel_state_lgl <-grepl(start_end_vowel,state.name)  #Q2
    state.name[vowel_state_lgl]    #Q3

[1] "Alabama"  "Alaska"   "Arizona"  "Idaho"    "Indiana"  "Iowa"     "Ohio"     "Oklahoma"
```

My question is, what is the use of `.` in Q1?

I know `.` is for any character and, in the case above, we want location begining with a vowel, but why `+[aeiou]{1}$` doesn't need `.`? In fact R reports error if using `+[aeiou]{1}.$`

So what is the appropriate way to use `.` in this situation?

Comment: `".*"` is the component. it says match any series of characters. Then `".*[aeiou]$"` says match any series of characters that end with a vowel. [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is an awesome reference.

Comment: `.` is the equivalent of a wild-card in regex it will match anything. the multiple operators like `* +` are saying match "any number" and "more than one" of whatever character came immediately before. I keep this cheat sheet book marked to help myself: https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a breakdown of how your RegEx reads:

```
^[AEIOU]{1}.+[aeiou]{1}$

^                          Start of a line
 [AEIOU]                   Match any single character inside the []. A single upper-case vowel
        {1}                Match the preceding token exactly once
           .               Match any character (depending on your RegEx engine and options this will behave with slight variation.)
            +              Match the preceding token as many times as possible. "Any character any number of times"
             [aeiou]{1}    Match a single lower-case vowel.
                       $   Match the end of a line.
```

To answer your question, `[aeiou]{1}$` doesn't need a `.` because it would read as such:

```
[aeiou]{1}.$

[aeiou]{1}      Match any lower-case vowel one time
          .     Match any other character one time
           $    Match end of line
```

Which means your RegEx would only match a line starting with an upper-case vowel.

I always say this before offering RegEx advice: I'm not a RegEx ninja; There's probably a better way to do this. With that said, if you need to match a line that starts with a case-insensitive vowel, use this instead:

`^[aeiouAEIOU].+[aeiouAEIOU]$`

Notice that I removed the redundant `{1}` qualifier. It should match one character by default.

Comment: THANK YOU! Thats a very explicit answer!